# Are there any Linux distros with a preconfigured user-friendly shell environment?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, distributions, utilities

I see so many Linux distros all around, and they all come with different look & feels and their own set of pre-installed GUI tools for most standard tasks. The default shell environment, however, is plain `bash` in most cases. I wonder if there are any distros that come with a more user-friendly configured shell?

I know that "user-friendly" is something to argue about and might mean different things to different people. But that's exactly why there there are so many different GUI-based distros. And I wonder why there aren't at least *some* CLI-based distros with different default shell configurations.

I spent quite a lot of time checking out different tools to improve my command line experience (I am thinking of stuff like [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf), [starship](https://starship.rs/), [zsh syntax highlighting](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting), [autosuggestions](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions), [zoxide](https://github.com/ajeetdsouza/zoxide/), [exa](https://github.com/ogham/exa), [fd](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd), [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep), [sd](https://github.com/chmln/sd), tmux, etc.). And there were so many occasions where I thought "This is so useful! Why isn't this standard?"

Lots of people share their shell configuration in the form of [dotfiles](https://dotfiles.github.io/). While this is definitely useful, it still is a lot of work to browse through all these repositories and understand what configuration has which effect.

So I googled a bit for command-line based distros that come with a preconfigured shell environment to have a useful starting point. I couldn't find anything alike, though. Do you know any distros containing a shell environment that offers more than just bash in its default configuration?

Comment: 1. I still don't understand what exactly you need. 2. I still don't understand why you cannot install the said utilities/scripts/etc manually. 3. What's good for you, might be excessive for someone else. 4. All this zoo of additional features requires maintenance and time.

Comment: Hi @ArtemS.Tashkinov. 1. I am looking for a Linux distribution that comes with a shell that is not pure bash in its default configuration. 2. Of course I can, I am just curious if anybody has done this in the form of a distribution. 3. That's true, and I already covered this in my question. 4. That's also true, but you can say this about desktop distributions as well, and obviously there are people investing their time to maintain those. So I think it's legit to assume that there might be people maintaining a CLI based distro as well.

Comment: When I briefly tried manjaro in a VM, found the default shell is zsh with a lot of useful plugins pre-installed. I didn't prefer it though.

Comment: @balki Ah, that's interesting, thanks for the hint!

Comment: @balki That's indeed exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. You should post it as an answer. Still curious if there are other distros with this kind of config, though.